# why the form can still be submit when the function return false?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Why can you still submit a form even though the function returns false?

```js
function submit() {
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return submit()">
  account : <input name="name" type="text" id="name"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your function name conflicts with the native submit action.
I've renamed it below.

```js
function submitter() {
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return submitter()">
  account : <input name="name" type="text" id="name"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Also see [Reserved words in JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm).

Answer (score 0):

[preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) work great to prevent default action like clics or submits..

```
 $('form').submit((ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault();
 })
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is not bound to Jquery. It exists in vanilla javascript as well.

Comment: Yes by default i wrote it in jquery but you can use javascript. You'r true

Comment: This provides an alternative method, but doesn't answer the OP's question: "Why can you still submit a form even though the function returns false?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a unique identifier on the form and use it to add an event listener in your javascript as below.

Also use event.preventDefault() to stop the default form submission action which works as in the code below. Hope this solves your problem :-)

```js
document.querySelector("#my-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="my-form" method="post">
  account : <input name="name" type="text" id="name"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```